# How to Show 2 LatLng as Initial Position in Flutter Google Map

Tags: google-maps, flutter

i'm doing (OLA, UBER) like app in flutter.i wanna show route from source and destination and to set initial camera position by covering two lat-long.

```
GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                compassEnabled: true,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: 
                LatLng(0.0, 0.0)), // <---- instead of single 
                // latlong, i wanna show both source and
                // destination
                markers: _createMarker(),
                polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(polyLines.values),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await mapController
    .animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(
        LatLngBounds(southwest: LatLongONE, northeast: LatLongTWO), 35))
```

those two southwest, northeast will be given by this
[enter link description here](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=00.00&destination=00.00&mode=driving&key=%22your_API_key%22)

google Api